# Triggers not Triggering, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers

I have set up a system whereby in the middle of each square of my chessboard there is an unrendered `circle` which has two colliders on it. One just allows it to collide with the board so it doesn't fall through, the other (bigger one) is a trigger. I am planning on using these triggers to determine which square the relavent pieces are on for my chess game.

However, none of the triggers appear to be triggering. Every piece has a collider and a rigidbody as required by the documentation. I have been trying for hours to get this to work but to no avail. I have tried jiggling with the rigidbodies and the colliders but nothing seems to work.

The test code I am using is extremely simple and is attached to each `Circle`:

```
public class Trigger : MonoBehaviour {

void onTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("Trigger Enter");
}
void onTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("Trigger Stay");
}
void onTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("Trigger Exit");
}
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated because I'm completely stumped at the moment.

[image: Screenshot of Unity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly embarassing but I guess it can catch the best of us. Rather than deleting the question I thought, as this appears to be a common proble, I would post the solution here.

`onTriggerEnter` needs to be `OnTriggerEnter` etc. Got to love case sensitive code!

Guess my attention to detail needs to improve.

Comment: Haha. Yes don't delete it, will be useful to others now and in the future :)